# Difference between curl file attachment and HTML form file upload

Tags: java, html, forms, curl, multipartform-data

What is the difference between the below

**Curl file upload :**
curl -v -F "file.png=@/home/jabong/Pictures/file.png" http://localhost:8889/fileuploadservice

**HTML Form Upload :**

```
<form action="http://localhost:8889/fileUploadService" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" />
    </p> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>
```

FileUploadService is developed using camel-jetty component and camel input exchange has attachments if we use the above curl command. If the HTML form upload is used, I am getting the file data inside webkit boundary in the body of the request. Can someone please explain what is the difference between the two.

Also, How to write this file data having web-kit boundary in a new file using camel components